# Suppress formatting characters in Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am building an Excel sheet in C# and there is one field that gets converted to scientific notation and I want it to stay text.  When I prepend the value with '=""' it displays it like this 20211104075106.399=" ", which is the correct value but I don't want the =" " at the end. This is how I am adding it to the value:

```
    excelWorksheet.Cells[intRow, 5] = string.Join("=\" ", row[4].ToString(), "\"");
```

Is there any way to suppress that? Thanks.

Comment: `String.Join` is **not** what you should be using. Use `String.Concat` or just use the `+` operator. The first parameter of `String.Join` is special: it's the `separator`. You should use named parameters to avoid that mistake in future.

Comment: Prepend the value with an apostrophe, as in `'20211104075106.399`

Comment: That fixed it thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

To force text formatting to a cell, you prepend the value with an apostrophe

```
excelWorksheet.Cells[intRow, 5] = $"'{row[4]}";
```